# Does an explicit temporary of an integral type qualify as an integral constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, type-conversion, clang

In the following code, `int()` is an explicit type conversion.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    void* ptr = int(); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Clang Compiler:**

```
source_file.cpp:5:11: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'void *' with an rvalue of type 'int'
    void* ptr = int(); 
      ^     ~~~~~
```

**GCC Compiler:**

```
Working fine.
```

So, Which compiler correct?

and, Does an explicit temporary of an integral type qualify as an integral constant expression?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but wanted to let you know you were probably downvoted because you're question says (non-pointer) integral temporary, but your code is assigning it to a pointer.  Also it seems hard to believe gcc accepted the program; even if it did, the program is still incorrect as presented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, an explicit temporary such as `int()` can be an integral constant expression (provided, of course, that it is actually constant). This is a red herring.

Your versions (and flags) of Clang and GCC seem to implement the null pointer constant behaviour from C++03 and C++11 respectively. The standard states that a null pointer literal, suitable for initializing your `void*`, is:

- **C++03**: [conv.ptr] "an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type **that evaluates to zero**", such as `0`, `int()` or `(1 - 1)`;
- **C++11** (onwards): [conv.ptr] "an integer literal **with value zero**" ("or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t"), which leaves only an actual `0` as an `int`-to-`void*` conversion candidate.

In any case, what you should use to initialize null pointers is `nullptr`.

Comment: Technically it's not *quite* restricted to just `0`. It could also be `0L`, `0LL`, or `'\0'`. Not really a significant difference though...